# responding to an HTTP POST requests

Tags: python, flask, slack-api

I need help responding to an HTTP POST request. I am trying to use slack slash and you need to respond in three seconds to their http post request. My code is like this

```
@app.route('/recover', methods = ['POST'])
def recover(data):
    if verify_signature(slack_signing_signature):
       send_message()
    data = {"response_type":"in_channel"}
    return jsonify(data)
```

My problem is that how can i return a response to slack first then do the actual stuff that I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread;

```py
from threading import Thread

def slack_it(sign):
    if verify_signature(sign):
       send_message()

@app.route('/recover', methods = ['POST'])
def recover(data):
    Thread(target=slack_it, args=(slack_signing_signature,), daemon=False).start()
    return jsonify({"response_type":"in_channel"})
```

Comment: For args did you mean 'sign'? Or what is slack_signature in the code example? thanks

Comment: slack_signing_signature in your code

Comment: Ok thanks, just wondering if it possible to use async for this as well or not?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/async-await/

Comment: thanks im getting a "RuntimeError: Working outside of request context." when testing on slack not sure how since it should be sending post request.